# ordenar dos columnas dependiendo de los datos más recientes ingresados

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

tengo un problema tengo una tabla que quiero ordenar por fecha para que los datos mas recientes queden primero y otra columna que es numérica que también quiero ordenar para que los campos que estén vacíos vayan debajo de los que no y si Lo hice con "orden", pero cuando lo hago, se rompe el orden descendente de la fecha.

¿Hay alguna forma de ordenar sin romper el orden de las fechas?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#servicios').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSider: true,
       "order": [[ 2, 'desc' ],[ 3, 'desc' ]],
      "pageLength": 50,
      "lengthMenu": [[5,10,50,-1], [5,10,50,"All"]]
    });
 });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.3/api/sum().js"></script>
<table id="servicios" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>&#10003;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td>$ 14.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>&#10003;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-05</td>
                <td>S/ 124.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>&#10003;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-03</td>
                <td>$ 14.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-02</td>
                <td>S/ 124.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-01</td>
                <td>$ 14.00</td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table>
```

agradecería si me pueden brindar información de como hacerlo

Comment: El orden es correcto, si ordenas los valores vacios hasta el final, las fechas ya no estarian ordenadas

Comment: pero hay alguna manera de que no se rompa el orden de las fechas

Answer (score 0):

En **datatables**, durante su uso, por defecto puedes ordenar por varias columnas pulsando sobre la tecla **Shift** (*Desplazamiento*). Primero selecciona la columna de la fecha y después pulsa la tecla **Shift** mientras seleccionas otras columnas.

En [este enlace](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html) encontrarás más información y otros métodos via código para hacerlo.